# Como accedo a un item dentro de un diccionario anidado sabiendo solo el item anterior al que estoy buscando

Tags: python, diccionarios

no estoy entendiendo como acceder al valor de un segundo key siendo mi base el valor del primer key, o sea, estoy intentando acceder al item "Año": 2012, siendo que lo único que tengo como referencia es "Título": "A"

```
{
        "Datos": [
            {
                "Titulo": "A",
                "Año": 2012,
                ]
            },
            {
                "Titulo": "B",
                "Año": 2007,
                ]
            }
```

Por lo que estuve averiguando, para acceder a un item especifico, debo saber su ubicación en el diccionario, realizando el print de abajo logré hallar el valor de Año, pero me gustaría automatizar la obtención de la ubicación, o sea, el 0:

```
print(diccionario["Datos"][0]["Año"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El diccionario que habías dejado como ejemplo tiene sintaxis incorrecta, supongo que sería esta:

```
diccionario = {
    "Datos": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
            "Año": 2012,
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
            "Año": 2007,
        }
    ]
}
```

Para tu problema, tendrás que recorrer los items de la lista del key "Datos" del diccionario, si el item tiene como título el deseado ("A"), se imprimirá su año (o lo que quieras hacer con él).

```
for item in diccionario["Datos"]:
    if item["Titulo"] == "A":
        print(item["Año"])
        break
```

Para obtener su posición (el 0 que dices), guardas el índice del for anterior (puedes hacerlo con enumerate() o simplemente haciendo un ubi+=1 en cada iteración)

```
ubi = -1
for i, item in enumerate(diccionario["Datos"]):
    if item["Titulo"] == "A":
        ubi = i
        break
print(ubi)


ubi = -1
for item in diccionario["Datos"]:
    ubi+=1
    if item["Titulo"] == "A":
        break
print(ubi)
```

Y si ya quieres hacerlo un poco enrevesado pero en sólo una línea

```
ubi = list(map(lambda item: item["Titulo"] == "A", diccionario["Datos"])).index(True)
print(ubi)
```

Comment: Genial, me encantó tu respuesta, al principio me confundí un poco sobre el funcionamiento del primer consejo en un diccionario muy grande (destinado a un JSON) pero era tan fácil como cambiar la "A" por la variable donde está alojado el input donde pregunto al usuario el titulo, gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Se puede hacer con:

```
z = [x for x in diccionario["Datos"] if x["Titulo"] == "A"][0]["Año"]
print(z)
```

Con `diccionario["Datos"]` obtenemos esta lista de diccionarios:

```
[{'Titulo': 'A', 'Año': 2012}, {'Titulo': 'B', 'Año': 2007}]
```

El `for x in diccionario["Datos"]` recorre cada diccionario en la lista. Si el diccionario cumple la condición `x["Titulo"] == "A"`, ese diccionario se agrega a la nueva lista:

```
[x for x in diccionario["Datos"] if x["Titulo"] == "A"]
```

produciendo

```
[{'Titulo': 'A', 'Año': 2012}]
```

Tengo entonces una lista con un diccionario. El diccionario es el primer item de la lista (`[0]`), y el año se extrae con `["Año"]`.

```
[{'Titulo': 'A', 'Año': 2012}][0]["Año"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Una forma más, que es realmente innecesaria puesto que las respuestas anteriores muestran formas mucho más simples y lógicas para lograr el objetivo, pero que incluyo aquí sólo para ilustrar una característica que viene en la última versión de Python (3.10, del 2 de agosto de 2021).

Se trata del llamado ***structural matching***, que es una especie de `switch/case` con superpoderes.

En este caso iteramos por la lista de diccionarios pero en lugar de usar un `if` para encontrar el que buscamos y después extraer de él el año, uso un *structural matching* que a la vez que "encaja" con el dato buscado, lo extrae. Este es el código:

```
for elemento in diccionario["Datos"]:
    match elemento:
        case {"Titulo": "A", "Año": año}:
             print(año)
```

Como ves, tras el `case` se especifica un patrón que indica qué campos ha de tener el diccionario buscado ("Titulo" y "Año") y qué valores han de tener (en el título ha de tener la cadena "A" literal, pero en el año puede tener cualquier cosa y lo que allí haya quedará capturado en la variable `año`).

Naturalmente para este caso como digo puede ser más simple usar `if`, pero quise poner esta respuesta para ir teniendo ejemplos de cómo se puede usar esta nueva característica del lenguaje.